# Cloud Functions and Storage: Is deleting file asynchronous?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

In my Google Cloud Functions script, I want to delete a Google Cloud Storage file by using the following code:

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')()

exports.deletePost = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    if(!context.auth) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called while authenticated.');
    }

    const the_post = request.query.the_post;

    const filePath = context.auth.uid + '/posts/' + the_post;
    const bucket = gcs.bucket('android-com')
    const file = bucket.file(filePath)
    const pr = file.delete()


});
```

The problem is that I also need to delete a Google Firebase Firestore database entry after having deleted the Storage file. So I would want to know if I could do it within, for example, a promise that would be returned by `delete`?

PS : I don't find the doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `file.delete()` is asynchronous and returns a Promise, as defined in the [Google Cloud Storage: Deleting objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-objects) documentation.

> To delete an object from one of your Cloud Storage buckets:

```js
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
// const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
// const filename = 'File to delete, e.g. file.txt';

// Deletes the file from the bucket
await storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .file(filename)
  .delete();

console.log(`gs://${bucketName}/${filename} deleted.`);
```

It's not overly clear, but because the `await` syntax is used, this implies that the result of the expression to it's right is a Promise.

**Note:** Most of the useful Google Cloud Storage documentation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/how-to).

Comment: If an error occured impeding the deletion, an exception is thrown, right? How could I catch it? (in the doc they use a function `ok()` ?)

Comment: Is my following code correct?  : `const promise = await gcs.bucket('android-framework-f3b92.appspot.com').file(filePath).delete();
 if(!promise.ok()) {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Unable to delete the image.');
 }
 // No error `

Comment: Normally, to catch an error on a Promise you would attach a `.catch((err) => {...})` onto the promise chain. But when you are using `await` syntax, the value of the rejected promise should be thrown like an exception and collectable by `try`/`catch` syntax.